# 'numpy.float64' object is not callable error for list

Tags: python, list, numpy

i dont understand why max function dont work.

```
import numpy as np
li_p=[1,2,3,44,3,444,5,6,7,22,4456]
print(type(li_p))
print(type(li_p[0]))
print(max(li_p))
```

this gives the output

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-38b2d24abf55> in <module>()
      3 print(type(li_p))
      4 print(type(li_p[0]))
----> 5 print(max(li_p))

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

if i do np.max it works.

Comment: Works for me... any more details you can provide?

Comment: It seems like you may have overwritten the "max" global variable with a variable of float type. Does the above code originate from somewhere else? Because then, you might want to find out where "max" is being set.

Comment: Never give a variable a name that might be the name of a function.

Comment: @veryverde ok.. I'll see where max  being set

Comment: when you do diagnostic prints, you should show the results.  We may see something that you overlooked.  But as others point out, the identify of `max` also needs to be checked.

Comment: i cheaked the  max and it indeed was assigned to something else.. so its solved now